# Can't normalize LiDAR point cloud with lasheight and -replace z (LAStools)

Tags: qgis, lidar, lastools, point-cloud, normalize

When I try to use lasheight with `-replace z` to normalize the point cloud, the height of points are changed (destroyed heights; see pictures below).

Without using `-replace z` everything is ok, but the normalized point cloud isn't obtained.

[image: no -replace z] [image: with -replace z]

Comment: The No. of points ~ 10,000,000.

Comment: The coordinate system is utm, and the datum is WGS84.

Comment: I use QGIS Nødebo 2.16, with "-replace_z".

Comment: I use: lasground, and then: lasheight (an unclassified point cloud without any raster model).

Comment: Considering the input file is an unclassified point cloud, and that you used lasground to generate a ground.las (i.e., a point cloud with only ground points); then use example 2 from my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides adding the ground reference for normalizing the point cloud, there were other issues I had to address. They were:

- bad scale factors x y z: 0.000000335839844, 0.000000499992188, 0.000000037939995 and bad offsets x y z: 31515000, 5686500, 42.900001525878906 of points, where scale factors had sub centimeter resolution.

So, before normalizing, I had to use the following command:

```
las2las -i input.las -rescale 0.01 0.01 0.01 -auto_reoffset -o fixed.laz
```

In the LAStools Google Group I posted more details about my LiDAR input file, and the full discussion until its resolution can be accessed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lastools/Uzr8Dp96K0w).

Answer (score 2):

Note the correct notation is `-replace_z` with an underline "_" before z (not `-replace z`).

Certify what you are using as the reference for normalization; i.e.; you need something to subtract from the point's elevation: usually a DTM (raster), but `lasheight` will accept the own point cloud if it is already classified regarding ground points (class = 2), or a separate .las file having only ground points.

That being said, the argument `-replace_z` is not designed to solely normalize the point cloud, but to replace permanently the elevation values for heights in the input file, i.e., the original file. Take a careful read in the `lasheight` [README](https://www.cs.unc.edu/%7Eisenburg/lastools/download/lasheight_README.txt) for more info.

Also, make sure the point cloud is in a projected coordinate system, such as UTM projection.

---

Examples, using `-replace_z`:

If the point cloud is already classified, including ground points:

```
lasheight -i *.las -replace_z.
```

If it is not classified, but there is a separate .las file having only ground points:

```
lasheight -i *.las -ground_points ground.las -replace_z
```

If it is not classified, the ground truth is a DTM (raster) instead of point data:

```
lasheight -i *.las -ground_points dtm.asc -replace_z
```

In the last example, it will also support other raster formats such as .csv, .bil, .txt.